# How to use Postgresql ts_delete function

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I am trying to use Postgresql Full Text Search. I read that the stop words (words ignored for indexing) are implemented via dictionary. But I would like to give the user a limited control over the stop words (insert new ones), so I grouped then in a table.
From the example below:

```
select strip(to_tsvector('simple', texto)) from longtxts where id = 23;
```

I can get the vector:

```
{'alta' 'aluno' 'cada' 'do' 'em' 'leia' 'livro' 'pedir' 'que' 'trecho' 'um' 'voz'}
```

And now I would like to remove the elements from the stopwords table:

```
select array(select palavra_proibida from stopwords);
```

That returns the array:

```
{a,as,ao,aos,com,default,e,eu,o,os,da,das,de,do,dos,em,lhe,na,nao,nas,no,nos,ou,por,para,pra,que,sem,se,um,uma}
```

Then, following documentation:

```
ts_delete(vector tsvector, lexemes text[])  tsvector    remove any occurrence of lexemes in lexemes from vector ts_delete('fat:2,4 cat:3 rat:5A'::tsvector, ARRAY['fat','rat'])
```

I tried a lot. For example:

```
select ts_delete((select strip(to_tsvector('simple', texto)) from longtxts where id = 23), array[(select palavra_proibida from stopwords)]);
```

But I always receive the error:

```
ERROR:  function ts_delete(tsvector, character varying[]) does not exist
LINE 1: select ts_delete((select strip(to_tsvector('simple', texto))...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`ts_delete` was introduced in PostgreSQL 9.6. Based on the error message, you're using an earlier version. You may try `select version();` to be sure.

When you land on the PostgreSQL online documentation with a web search, it may correspond to any version. The version is in the URL and there's a *"This page in another version"* set of links at the top of each page to help switching to the equivalent doc for a different version.

Comment: Hmmm, you are right! I'm using 9.5. I will try another approuch. Thank you very much!